# Gcloud instance can't ping another one

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform

I have 2 instances running on Compute engine, although the documentation says that I'm able to ping and establish a communication between these VMs I can't. I've tried the ping with VM name and ipv4 address. I also tried to configure new work-group for both VMs and nothing.

Here's the link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-ip-addresses

> If you are communicating between instances in the same network, you
> can send packets to an instance using the instance name, and the
> network automatically resolves the name to the internal IP address of
> the instance.

My VMs configuration:

Both are in the same network
[image: instances]
[image: Ipconfig from web01]
[image: Ipconfig from sql01]

I even turn off the firewalls

[image: firewall off]

But no connection between at all.

[image: web not pinging sql]

Anyone passed for the same? someone knows what is going on?
How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each network in Google Compute Engine has its own firewall configuration which by default will block incoming traffic to your VM. See the [firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls) documentation to see how the default network is configured and how to apply similar rules to your custom network.

Comment: I can ping each instance from my computer. but I can't between each other. There's a firewall rule that allow incoming ICMP traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 to rede-google-cloud. The problem is my two instances is on the same network. That means the traffic will not pass trough any router. **There's something I'm missing?** Thanks for help.

Comment: That should suffice - when I added a rule for 0.0.0.0/0, protocol icmp, and left  'applies to tags' blank, I was able to ping both Windows and Linux VMs from within the same network (same and different subnets). Is the networking in Windows fully configured via DHCP or is there some manual configuration? Have you tried with any other OS versions? Are there any non-default routes on your GCE network? Have you had the opportunity to shutdown (or event delete / re-create) the instances to see if the problem is a bad cache somewhere?

Comment: I created **2 debian** machines on the same network, and **ping is working** between them. Then I create a new windows instance and I can ping between debian and windows new instance. However my other two instances still unreachable. I'll start from beginning with new instances. see if it'll work

Comment: I don't know what is happening, but I created 2 new windows instances and ping work, but the old ones don't work.

Comment: I had this issue and Angus is right - I had to add 3 separate rules for internal access - ingress from 172.16.16.0/24  - one rule for TCP, one for ICMP, one for UDP  (a global rule for all did not work).  Now everything can ping and do file shares.  So - check all the firewalls, drop them all at first, then re-enable.

Answer (score 5):

This is due to firewall rules. You need to add the `allow-icmp` network tag in the Network tags section of the instances edit page > [image]

You can create new Network tags to open up new ports/protocols in the `VPC Network>Firewall rules` section:

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
Please note that the 0.0.0.0/0 subnet used on the screenshot above opens up the ports to the entire internet and I only used it for demonstration purposes to avoid sharing my IPs. I would **STRONGLY** advise against using that subnet for firewall rules in a production environment. The internet is a dark and scary place.

Answer (score 4):

This happens to us from time to time - suddenly our 2 instances cannot reach each other through API or even ping. Even though we haven't changed any firewall rules or anything. I guess it's some GCloud glitch.

Nothing we have tried works, except for restarting the instances, then everything works again. So, if anyone has the same, and nothing seems to help the issue, I suggest, as a last resort, to reboot the instances.

Comment: This just happened to me - after restarting the vm, the ping worked. Nothing was changed in firewall rules or vm configs. So weird

Answer (score 2):

Be sure the firewall rules include the GCE subnet. In your case, it would mean that 10.10.0.0/24 has icmp allowed.

I'm not sure why the firewall rules apply within the network subnet, but apparently they do.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not change network and or firewall rules and use default network and firewall rules then simply edit hosts file *(open hosts on all vm, copy hosts line for each vm and add its all other vm)* and then try ping. I have tried same between three centos instance and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you restart the network on VMs in order to work it fine.
This helped me pretty well.